# Interaction between classes and struct

Tags: c#, .net, struct, class-design

OK, so a class in my project goes through this method.

```
public static MemberName SplitTdsName(string tdsName)
    {
        NameSplitter preSplitName = new NameSplitter(tdsName);
        return preSplitName;
    }
```

MemberName is a struct:

```
public struct MemberName
{
    public string Title;
    public string FirstNames;
    public string LastNames;

    public MemberName(string title, string firstNames, string lastNames)            
    {            
        Title = title;
        FirstNames = firstNames;
        LastNames = lastNames;
    }
}
```

And NameSplitter class:

```
public NameSplitter(string fullName)
    {
        nameInFull = fullName;
        SetAllowedTitles();
        SplitNamesAndRemovePeriods();
        SetTitles();
        MemberName splitName = new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames);
        return splitName;
    }
```

This won't work because when I change public NameSplitter to public MemberName NameSplitter the SplitTdsName method tells me NameSplitter doesn't have a method that takes one argument.

I don't know how to work around this or **get it to work**. Do I need to change NameSplitter to a NameSplitter a static class?

Note: **I KNOW THE CODE IS WRONG**

Went with:

```
public static MemberName SplitTdsName(string tdsName)
    {
        return NameSplitter.NameSplitter(tdsName);
    }

public static MemberName NameSplitter(string fullName)
    {
        nameInFull = fullName;
        SetAllowedTitles();
        SplitNamesAndRemovePeriods();
        SetTitles();
        MemberName splitName = new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames);
        return splitName;
    }

    public MemberName(string title, string firstNames, string lastNames)            
    {            
        Title = title;
        FirstNames = firstNames;
        LastNames = lastNames;
    }
```

Comment: Does this code ever compiles?

Comment: You seem to be trying to `return` something from what I assume is the `NameSplitter` constructor - you can't do that.  Please provide the full `NameSplitter` code.

Comment: Your constructor for NameSplitter cannot return anything other than a NameSplitter class, it can't return a MemberName class.  Perhaps you want a simple constructor then a method to 'split' the string and return the MemberName object

Comment: @sll Code never compiles no. I realise this interaction is wrong, I just don't know how to make it right.

Comment: It's not an interaction issue, it's more of coding error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement the class like:

```
    public static class NameSplitter
    {
        public static MemberName Split(string fullName)
        {
            ...
            MemberName splitName = new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames);
            return splitName;
        }
    }
```

and then use as `MemberName mn = NameSplitter.Split("<your data here>");`

Final code can look like:

```
    public static class YourClass
    {
        ...
        public static MemberName SplitTdsName(string tdsName)
        {
            MemberName preSplitName = NameSplitter.Split(tdsName);
            return preSplitName;
        }
    }

    public static class NameSplitter
    {
        ...
        public static MemberName Split(string fullName)
        {
            nameInFull = fullName;
            SetAllowedTitles();
            SplitNamesAndRemovePeriods();
            SetTitles();
            MemberName splitName = new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames);
            return splitName;
        }
    }

    public struct MemberName
    {
        public string Title;
        public string FirstNames;
        public string LastNames;

        public MemberName(string title, string firstNames, string lastNames)
        {
            Title = title;
            FirstNames = firstNames;
            LastNames = lastNames;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your code, it is clear it won't compile.

1) You can't have a `return` in a constructor.

```
public NameSplitter(string fullName)
{
     ...
     return splitName;
}
```

2) The return type and return statement must agree. Here you are return a `NameSplitter` but the function promised a `MemberName` :

```
public static MemberName SplitTdsName(string tdsName)
{
   NameSplitter preSplitName = new NameSplitter(tdsName);
   return preSplitName;
}
```

---

As a quick fix (maybe not complete, and untested)

```
// class NameSplitter
public NameSplitter(string fullName)
    {
        nameInFull = fullName;
        SetAllowedTitles();
        SplitNamesAndRemovePeriods();
        SetTitles();
        //MemberName splitName = new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames);
        //return splitName;
    }

public MemberName MemberName   // readonly property
{
    get { return new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames); }
}
```

And then the method becomes

```
public static MemberName SplitTdsName(string tdsName)
{
    NameSplitter preSplitName = new NameSplitter(tdsName);
    return preSplitName.MemberName ;
}
```

But I'm not convinced that MemberName should be a struct, a class would be a good choice too.

Comment: I thought as much, so how do I make that class return a MemberName?

Comment: A class cannot **return** anything. You can have a static method for that, or store the result in a property that is read by another object. Nothing else

Comment: So if I make three properties in my NameSplitter class (titles, firstNames and LastNames) then I can access those properties from TdsTransformer and create a MemberName from that?

Answer (score 1):

You should make the method a static method that returns a MemberName and assign the result to a MemberName variable, not a NameSplitter (in your SplitTdsName method)

Answer (score 1):

//Existing code

```
public struct MemberName
{
    public string Title;
    public string FirstNames;
    public string LastNames;

    public MemberName(string title, string firstNames, string lastNames)            
    {            
        Title = title;
        FirstNames = firstNames;
        LastNames = lastNames;
    }
}
```

//Modified Code below

```
public class NameSplitter
{

    // Added a property for returning splitName value thru' class
    private MemberName splitName;
    public MemberName SplitName
    {
        get { return splitName; }
        private set { splitName = value; }
    }

    public NameSplitter(string fullName)
    {
        nameInFull = fullName;
        SetAllowedTitles();
        SplitNamesAndRemovePeriods();
        SetTitles();

        splitName = new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames);

       // return splitName; // Can't be done in a constructor and has to be returned via public property
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
public static MemberName SplitTdsName(string tdsName)
    {
        NameSplitter preSplitName = new NameSplitter(tdsName);
        return preSplitName; // I don't understand why you're returning NameSplitter
                             // when method's return type is MemberName.
    }
```

2)

```
public NameSplitter(string fullName)
    {
        nameInFull = fullName;
        SetAllowedTitles();
        SplitNamesAndRemovePeriods();
        SetTitles();
        MemberName splitName = new MemberName(titles, firstNames, lastNames);
        return splitName; // How would a constructor return something?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My judgment is that, you must go back to your c# bible and review what you are trying to achieve and the design.

To answer your question, see the reworked sample

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
    public static MemberName SplitTdsName(string tdsName)
    {
        NameSplitter preSplitName = new NameSplitter(tdsName);
        return preSplitName.GetMemberName();
    } 
}
public struct MemberName
{
    public string Title;
    public string FirstNames;
    public string LastNames;

    public MemberName(string title, string firstNames, string lastNames)
    {
        Title = title;
        FirstNames = firstNames;
        LastNames = lastNames;
    }
}
public class NameSplitter
{
    MemberName _memberName;
    public NameSplitter(string fullName)
    {
        _memberName = new MemberName("title", "firstName", "lastName");
    }

    public MemberName GetMemberName()
    {
        return _memberName;
    }
}
```